# Cannot convert double into double [] error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, double, incompatibletypeerror

For a project, I have to split a string array into individual numbers and then set up a sequence by parsing the numbers into a double array.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sequence
{
   // the numbers in the sequence
   private double[] sequence;

   // sets up sequence by parsing s 
   public Sequence(String s)
   {
       String[] numbers = s.split(", ");
       double[] storage = new double [numbers.length];
       for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x = x+1) {
       storage = Double.parseDouble(numbers[x]);
      }
  }
```

For some reason, when I try to compile this I get an error saying

incompatible types:double cannot be converted to double[]

I have looked online for solutions but I am a complete beginner at Java and really don't know what to do here.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it, especially without having to add other methods that I don't understand?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Think of storage as a book of doubles, when you use `storage = Double.parseDouble(numbers[x]);` You forgot to tell it what "page" in storage you want to put that double on. (`storage[page] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[x]);`) EDIT: I didn't see the answers posted before this comment.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
storage[x] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[x]);
```

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)

> **public static double parseDouble(String s)**
>
> Returns a new double initialized to the value
>   represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf
>   method of class Double.

and **storage** is an array so compiler says `incompatible types:double cannot be converted to double[]`.Instead you can store each element one by one by specifying array index `storage[index]`.

Answer (score 0):

`storage` is the array that you're storing things in.  It has a type of `double[]`.  What you're doing is assigning a `double` to a `double[]` by invocation of this statement:

```
storage = Double.parseDouble(numbers[x]);
```

You want to store each individual element inside of the storage array as the parsed result of some other element from the numbers array.  Use this syntax instead:

```
storage[x] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

storage is an Array which holds double values, whilst Double.parseDouble returns a double, thus you should use

storage[x] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[x]);